# How to improve my boolean indexing in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm struggling with a simple pandas algo for stock market trading. Nothing serious or complicated, I just want to learn how to do it in python.

What I am trying to do is

- buy stocks when signal turns True, and pay for it with the cash (so cash goes down, stock position goes up
- When signal turns false, sell stocks and add the result to the cash.

But I can't get this to work. I could get this to work with looping, but that would be too time consuming. Any suggestions?

```
## data set
close=[21.02,21.05,21.10,21.22, 22.17,22.13,22.07]
signal=[False,True,True,True,False,True,True]
data={'close':close, 'signal':signal}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['cash']=1000
df['trade']=0
df['pos']=0

## if signal turns True, buy stocks
buysubset = ((df.signal==True) & (df.signal.shift(1)==False))
sellsubset = ((df.signal==False) & df.signal.shift(1)==True)
df.loc[buysubset,'trade']=(df.cash/df.close).astype(int)
df.loc[buysubset,'cash']=df.cash-(df.trade*df.close)
df.loc[sellsubset,'trade']=-df.pos.shift(1)

## if previous row has position, keep the position if the signal is still True
df['pos']=df.trade.mask(df.signal & (df.trade == 0)).ffill().astype(int)
```

I get this as a result:

```
   close  signal     cash  trade  pos
0  21.02   False  1000.00    0.0    0
1  21.05    True    10.65   47.0   47
2  21.10    True  1000.00    0.0   47
3  21.22    True  1000.00    0.0   47
4  22.17   False  1000.00   -0.0    0
5  23.34    True     4.15   45.0   45
```

But would like to get this :

```
       close  signal     cash  trade  pos
    0  21.02   False  1000.00    0.0    0
    1  21.05    True    10.65   47.0   47
    2  21.10    True    10.65    0.0   47
    3  21.22    True    10.65    0.0   47
    4  22.17   False  1052.62  -47.0    0
    5  23.34    True     2.57   45.0   45
```

Comment: I think you need some form of looping, as the amount you buy and sell later would depend upon the profits you previously made.

Comment: Hmm yes I was afraid so. But it's a bit complicated when dealing with 2 million lines, it takes too much time to process. Also, I'm not sure I can do it with just one loop.